# Fetch res.json() Attempt to invoke intergace method 'java.lang.String...'

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I'm trying to convert a response from *fetch* function into *json* format but when I do so I get an error **Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.string com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMap.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference**.

Here is my code snippet with fetch function:

```
export const fetchAllUsers = () => {
fetch('http://192.168.1.103:3000/api/userData')
    .then(res => {
        res.json();
        //console.warn('res keys = ' + Object.keys(res))
    })
}
```

If comment back the row with *console.warn* I see the following **"res keys = type, status, ok, statusText, headers, url, _bodyInit, _bodyBlod, bodyUsed"**.

*bodyUsed = false*

*status = 200*

*type = default*

Why I can't convert a response into *json* format? Or is there any another way to do so?

**UPDATE**

I've added the second `then` but I still get the error and the **console.warn('res is json')** is not running:

```
export const fetchAllUsers = () => {
fetch('http://192.168.1.103:3000/api/userData')
    .then(res => {
        res.json();
        //console.warn('res keys = ' + Object.keys(res));
    })
    .then(res => {
        console.warn('res is json');
        console.warn(res);
    })
}
```

**UPDATE_2**

I've run `fetch` function with another url but still got the problem. It seems like `.json()` causes the error. When I'm trying to console the result of fetch in the first `.then()` I get json object with *type, status* etc keys.

```
export const fetchAllUsers = () => {
    fetch(`http://${localIP}:${port}/api/userData`)
        //.then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => console.warn('JSON: ' + json))
        .catch(e => console.warn('ERROR: ' + e))
}
```

**UPDATE_3**

Forgot to mention that I'm creating an Android app with React Native. For testing I'm using a physical smartphone. Chrome version there is 73.0.3683.

I've replaced my `fetch` query with the following:

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json));
```

But still get the same error.

When I run it in https://jsfiddle.net/ it works. So the reason is hidden inside the code execution on a smartphone.

Comment: add second `then` after first one. `.then(res=>res.json()).then(res=>"now res is json");`

Comment: Thanks for your comment but it didn't help. Please see "UPDATE" section.

Comment: whats your react native version number?

Comment: `"react": "^16.8.3" and "react-native": "^0.59.4"`

Answer (score 0):

There must be more context to your problem; see the below snippet. This clearly works.

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json));
```

Comment: It seems like **.json()** function causes the error. I've run your snippet but got the same error.

Comment: Perhaps your browser does not implement the `fetch` api? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API#Browser_compatibility

Comment: I'm creating an Android app with React-Native. For testing I use physical smartphone. The Chrome version there is 73.0.3683.90